# User authentication: prepare vs get_current_user in tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, coroutine, python-asyncio

I need to authenticate a user from a cookie in an application running on Tornado. I need to parse the cookie and load the user from the DB using the cookie content. On checking out the [Tornado RequestHandler documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=requesthandler#tornado.web.RequestHandler.current_user), there are 2 ways of doing it:

- by overriding `prepare()` method of `RequestHandler` class.
- by overriding `get_current_user()` method of `RequestHandler` class.

I'm confused with the following statement:

> Note that `prepare()` may be a coroutine while `get_current_user()` may
>   not, so the latter form is necessary if loading the user requires
>   asynchronous operations.

I don't understand 2 things in it:

1. What does the doc mean by saying that `get_current_user()` may not be a coroutine? What does *may not* mean here? Either it can be a coroutine, or it can't.
2. Why is the *latter* form, i.e. `get_current_user()`, required if async operation is required? If `prepare()` *can be* a coroutine and `get_current_user()` *may not*, then shouldn't `prepare()` be used for async operations?

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Here, "may not be a coroutine" means "is not allowed to be a coroutine" or "must not be a coroutine". The language used is confusing and it should probably be changed to say "must not".
2. Again, the docs are confusing: in this sentence `prepare()` is mentioned first, but before this sentence are two examples and `get_current_user` is first. "Latter" refers to the second example which uses `prepare()`.

So in summary, it always works to override `prepare()` and set `self.current_user`, whether you need a coroutine or not. If you don't need a coroutine to get the current user, you can override `get_current_user()` instead and it will be called automatically the first time `self.current_user` is accessed. It doesn't really matter which one you choose; you can use whichever feels more natural to you. (The reason we have two different methods is that `get_current_user()` is older but we had to use a different method for coroutines)

Answer (score 0):

### 1

The recommended way of getting current user is to use `RequestHandler.current_user` property. This property is actually a function, it returns `RequestHandler._current_user` if set, otherwise it tries to set it with call of `get_current_user`.

Because of `current_user` is a property - it can't be yielded, therefore `get_current_user` can't be coroutine function.

Of course you could, read cookie and call db, authenticate user in `get_current_user`, but only in blocking (sync) manner.

### 2

In the the [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=requesthandler#tornado.web.RequestHandler.current_user) you quoted, the latter example is the one with `prepare`.